# When I add a JPG image in Codename One resource browser, it breaks

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I have an image of rather large resolution (9332 x 5116). When I go to the codename one editor, to add image, I can add the image, but then when I get back into the editor, the left-side menu doesn't display properly. To be more specific, it doesn't redraw when I'm in the Multi-image or All Images menu. The only way to go back to normal is to do a "Delete unused images."

Is this a known issue? I'd hate to sacrifice image quality.

Any advice greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is WAY too big to fit into any device and would crash many devices when they try to open it. The designer wasn't built to handle images so large, you can run it with more RAM but the solution is to use an image of realistic size.